# Rotate object by 90 degrees?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, object, rotation

I know this has been answered like 1000 times, but I just don't know how exactly should I code.
All I want is when the platform changes its position on the x or the z axis, then rotate the whole platform by 90 degrees.
I tried it with a platform.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0), so I think there is more to do.
The code itself:

```
    public GameObject platform;
    public Transform lastPlatform;
    Vector3 lastPosition;
    Vector3 newPos;
    bool stop;

    private Quaternion rotationQuaternion;

    void Start()
    {
        lastPosition = lastPlatform.position;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnPlatforms());

    rotationQuaternion = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SpawnPlatforms()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            GeneratePosition();

        Instantiate(platform, newPos, rotationQuaternion * Quaternion.identity);

            lastPosition = newPos;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }

    void GeneratePosition()
    {
        newPos = lastPosition;

        int rand = Random.Range(0, 2);

        if (rand > 0)
        {
            newPos.x += 1.5f;
        transform.rotation = rotationQuaternion * Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0); //one way i tried
        }
        else
        {
            newPos.z += 1.5f;
            platform.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0) //another way I tried
        }
    }
```

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: I don't see where you are rotating anything ...

Comment: Because I deleted from it. I tried to rotate in the random if statement, so when the platforms position changes, it will rotate as well. But it doesnt.

Comment: Please show what you tried ;)

Comment: I edited the post, please take a look. Might be horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for the problem. Maybe could be helpful for someone, so here you go:

```
public struct SpawnPoint
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Quaternion orientation;

        public void Step(float distance)
        {
            if (Random.value < 0.5)
            {
                position.x += distance;
                orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                position.z += distance;
                orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            }

            //orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0) * orientation;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _spawn.position = lastPlatform.position;
        _spawn.orientation = transform.rotation;
    }
```

From now on, all what's left to do is Instantiate:

```
var newPlatform = Instantiate(platform, _spawn.position, _spawn.orientation);
```

Huge thanks to derHugo for giving me a start on how to do that!

Comment: When does `Step` get called? It's unclear how this connects with the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

So as I see it currently there are multiple issues / unclear things

- you are rotating about `90°` each `0.1` seconds, so within 1 second you rotate about `900°`. That sounds to me like it is simply way to fast.
- You also rotate `transform` and not the platform
- `platform` seems to be a **Prefab** in the assets so it makes no sense to rotate it

You probably want to do

```
void GeneratePosition()
{
    newPos = lastPosition;

    int rand = Random.Range(0, 2);

    if (rand > 0)
    {
        newPos.x += 1.5f;
    }
    else
    {
        newPos.z += 1.5f;
    }

    // rather directly rotate the quaternion parameter
    // if you are going to do the same thing in both cases anyway I would rather extract it right away
    rotationQuaternion *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
}
```

and then also

```
// Rotating by "Quaternion.idendity" has no effect
Instantiate(platform, newPos, rotationQuaternion);
```

---

Still that sounds like a lot of spawning to me, maybe you would want to look into [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It still somehow doesn't work, platforms are not rotating.
Yes, a lot of platforms do spawn. I am willing to solve it, so one platform generates by each input.